# Angular Post Service

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to wrap my HTTP POST request to a service which then could be used to retrieve data from my PHP API, But the problem is that I don't know how to let services use the user's inputted data.
Here have a look at my code

```
<form ng-submit="myCtrl.submit()" name="myForm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.user.name">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.user.message">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
</form>
```

My JS code

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.service('PostService', function($http) {
    return{
        success: function() {
            return $http.post('process3.php', self.user);
        }
    };
});
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['PostService', function(PostService) {
    var self = this;
    var user = {};
    self.submit = function() {
        PostService.success().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.data);
    });
    }
}]);
```

php code:

```
<?php

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

@$name = $request->name;
@$message = $request->message;

$records = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'message' => $message
    );
echo json_encode($records);
?>
```

I am not able to find the solution to this problem, as I have searched through google and Stackoverflow again and again. But I don't even know whether what I am asking is illogical or not. But if you are able to understand the problem and have better way to deal with it then please let me know.

Basically I want to wrap my POST requests in a service just like we do with the GET ones.

Comment: What about user as parameter in 'success: function()'? Like 'sucess: function(user)'

Comment: Yeah, I was missing that only! Thanks for commenting back! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass use object to success function.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.service('PostService', function($http) {
    return{
        success: function(user) {
            return $http.post('process3.php', user);
        }
    };
});
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['PostService', function(PostService) {
    var self = this;
    self.user = {};
    self.submit = function() {
        PostService.success(self.user).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.data);
    });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! :D it worked like a charm!, The thing which I was missing was to send object in `PostService.success(self.user)` 
Cheers!